# Display the minimum value from table cell values jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I am trying to store the table cells values into an array and then compare them to get the lowest value which I intend to display in a div, but I am getting **NaN** as the output, what am I doing wrong?

```
 var arr = new Array();
 arr[0] = parseFloat($("#cell1").html());
 arr[1] = parseFloat($("#cell2").html());
 arr[2] = parseFloat($("#cell3").html());
 arr[3] = parseFloat($("#cell4").html());

 var min =  Math.min.apply(Math, arr);              
 $("#convert").text(min)
```

Comment: Could you plz post your html.

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/k7wFb/ Please post your html

Comment: Is `cell1`,`cell2`,`cell3` etc are tr `id's` in your table?

Comment: I can smell that the problem is you have not only plain number but some extra tags in your `td`s. Try `.text()` instead of `.html()` and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks guys, problem solved. It was a mistake in the html.

Comment: Moar DRY way `var values = $('[id^=cell]').map(function(_, el){return parseFloat($(el).text());});`